# Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am doing a shiny app where I have multiple functions. The concept:
User types in some text. From a database are rows extracted which contain the text. Then I am doing some kmeans, ngrams etc. If a retype the text and run it again it will fail and print: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows. It was working fine until I used functions. Here some code:

This function is in global

```
  kmeans_model <-kmeans(dist.matrix.jaccard,
                        centers = recommended.clusters,
                        iter.max = iters, algorithm = "Forgy")
}
```

I use the function in server in this way:

```
kmeans<-reactive({
    dist.matrix.jaccard<-dist.matrix.jaccard()
    output<-outputSummary()
    stop.clustering<-output[[2]]
    recommended.clusters<-min(stop.clustering)
    getKmeans(dist.matrix.jaccard, recommended.clusters,200)
  })
```

Then every time I use kmeans I do this

```
kmeans<-kmeans()
kmeans$cluster should refer to the calculated clusters
```

What should I change to get the functions working everytime a user updates the text provided?

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible example** or a link to the repository you are working on.